# AlarmManager and App Standby mode: can setAndAllowWhileIdle() handle it?

Tags: android

According to https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms :

> Your app will enter App Standby mode when it is idle, meaning the user has not used it for a period of time and the app does not have a foreground process. When the app is in App Standby alarms are deferred just like in Doze mode. This restriction is lifted when the app is no longer idle or if the device is plugged in to a power supply.

According to the same site:

> If you must have an alarm fire even in Doze mode you can use either setAndAllowWhileIdle() or setExactAndAllowWhileIdle().

Is the same valid for App StandBy Mode?